# My screen lock is set to "PIN", and I can't change it to "Swipe". Why not?

Tags: settings, lock-screens, security, device-administrator

I have tried to do the fix as suggested on here however my swipe option states it was disabled by administrator or something like that. Not sure how I even set a PIN in the first place. How do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have added VPN connections.

Usually VPN connection requires minimum Pattern/PIN/Password active, and while you have VPN connection created you can't disable it.

To check does you have it, and to delete it go to Settings -> More under Wireless & Networks-> VPN. *Keep in mind, this can be different on other Android version, you can search Google for your device.*

If there is present connection, after removing them you should be able to change Lock screen settings.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings-security and clear credentials.